# Confused on importing python module runtime

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

Dear all am trying to import a python module (from admincases import admincases) in runtime and facing issues on that.requesting your guidance on the same.

```
import os
import threading
import sys
import Queue
import unittest
import time
import logging
from functions import functions
from functions import db_connect
from one import ParametrizedTestCase
#from admincases import admincases
import MySQLdb as mdb

class inittest(unittest.TestCase):

    fun = functions()
    db = db_connect()
    cur = db.db_conn()
    cur.execute ("SELECT * FROM testcase")
    testcases = cur.fetchall ()
    for testcase in testcases:
        print "%s, %s" % (testcase[0], testcase[1])
        import_string = "from " + testcase[1] + " import " + testcase[1]
        print import_string
        exec import_string
        case = str_to_class(testcase[1])
        print case
        print "Number of rows returned: %d" % cur.rowcount
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(ParametrizedTestCase.parametrize(case, param=EppQueue,queue1=CrQueue))
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
    raw_input("keyy")
```

when this code is executed i get the below error:

```
 return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], str)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'admincases'
```

dont know what is the mistake

Regards
Venkat.S

Comment: `#from admincases import admincases` is in a comment?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yes that is the module i am trying to load dynamically

Comment: is it in the same dir as this script if its a package does it have `__init__.py` inside that folder? what does `admincases` actually have or is?

Comment: @Ragav `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'admincases'` is telling you that theres nothing in `admincases` that has a name `admincases`

Comment: @samy.vilar yes it is in the same directory and it does not have any init method call..it contains test procedures

Comment: @Ragav then you probably want to import those procedures `from admincases import proc1, proc2` and so on. you could do `from admincases import *` but please don't its quite dangerous, leading to subtle bugs.

Comment: @Ragav: *where* in the code is the exception raised? knowing this would help us help you.

Comment: @samy.vilar if that is the case if i run the code in hard coded pattern it runs successfully sayin like -- from admincases import admincases -- case = str_to_class(testcase[1]) ... it just works fine

Comment: @Ragav so whats the problem again?

Comment: @samy.vilar the issue theses classes prepared by users with their own style of name where they will upload the file via a small GUI to the system path and i then have to load all available tests dynamically and run them

Comment: @Ragav much better, you should have said so earlier, then you must verify that they actually have the classes before importing them. I take it this is your issue `exec import_string`  `inspect` http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html , might help you, eitherway this is extremely dangerous please reconsider another design, maybe nosetests.

Comment: @samy.vilar this is the blog which i followed..FYI : http://technogeek.org/python-module.html

Comment: @Ragav I don't want to get into an argument, that post is 5 years old, in the python community or tech community in general its quite old, things have changed quite a bit, I wish you the best of luck if have any more questions I would be happy to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

As samy.vilar hinted to, it looks like you should make sure that the `admincases` module has an `admincases` variable. In fact, your code does `from admincases import admincases`.

My guess is that if you make `from admincases import admincases` work, then your code should work.

Comment: yes it does work when i import "from admincases import admincases" but i have to do this IMPORT dynamically that is where i am facing issue

Answer (score 0):

i achieved it via using below method:

```
test_mod = __import__(testcase[1], fromlist=[])
test_class =  getattr(test_mod, testcase[1])
```